# Modeling rubber foams

Tags: resource-recommendations, elasticity

Are there any good papers/texts on the subject of modeling the dynamics of rubber foams? So far I haven't found any good papers/texts that cover this particular subject and I've done some searching.

I'm interested in how the internal geometry (i.e. distribution of empty space) affects the behavior of the material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In continuum mechanics terms:
There is Coussy, Olivier: Mechanics of porous continua, Wiley 1995. I do not have access to it at the moment, but I remember it having a chapter about viscoelastic porous continua, that might be worth checking out.